# C++: Inputting text as char* throws IStream nullptr error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, istream

I am running a simple C++ program (Visual Studio 2017) that requires user input.

This is how I collect that input:

```
int main()
{
    char* in;
    in = '\0';
    std::cout << "Move?\n";
    std::cin >> *in;
}
```

However, an exception is thrown on the last line:

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.
**_Ch** was nullptr.
```

When I take a closer look, the error is thrown from within the `istream` class at line `910`:

```
template<class _Elem,
    ...

    if (_Ok)
        {   ...
        if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(), _Meta))
            _State |= ios_base::eofbit | ios_base::failbit;
        else
            _Ch = _Traits::to_char_type(_Meta); // ERROR THROWN HERE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not use `char*`. Use `std::string`.

Comment: you have a pointer to a char, but no character, and what you actually want is a string

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. @idclev 463035818 I changed the type to a string, but the `std::cin >> in;` line then says that no operator found which takes a right hand argument of type "string"

Comment: @TedLyngmo I made a typo, I did use ">>"

Comment: Does your program look like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/bMqnad)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yep that's it - though I did not include <string> explicitly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo explicitly importing <string> solved the issue, thanks